# How to add Placeholder values to Flask_admin form_create_rules?

Tags: forms, flask, placeholder, flask-admin

Using Flask_Admin, I have a View/Model `Movie` which will have a field `genre` which will be a String, either `"horror"`, `"action"` or `"comedy"`.
For the Movie create form in flask_admin, I have:

```
class MovieView(ModelView):
    column_list = ['id', 'name', 'genre', 'director']
    form_create_rules = ('name', 'genre', 'director')
```

but the Movie Create form shows a blank input for the 'genre' field. How do I add placeholder values so admins know what values to put in that field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [form_args](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_args) to pass in WTForms [render_kw](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#the-field-base-class) values. For example:

```
class MovieView(ModelView):
    column_list = ['id', 'name', 'genre', 'director']
    form_create_rules = ('name', 'genre', 'director')

    form_args = {
        'name': {
            'render_kw': {
                'placeholder': 'Enter name'
            }
        },
        'genre': {
            'render_kw': {
                'placeholder': 'Enter genre'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! It was impossible to find the 'render_kw' stuff in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, form_args is not work.
It cost me an hour to implent the feature

I had to use "form_widget_args"

```
class MovieView(ModelView):
    column_list = ['id', 'name', 'genre', 'director']
    form_create_rules = ('name', 'genre', 'director')

    form_widget_args = {
        'name': {
            'placeholder': 'Enter name'
        },
        'genre': {
            'placeholder': 'Enter genre'
        }
    }
```